# Is there any limitations as to what can be stored in gitolite-admin?

Tags: gitolite

I know that the gitolite-admin repository contains the gitolite.conf and the keydir directory.

Can I add arbitrary files and objects to the gitolite-admin repository without repercussions?

Here, I'm specifically looking to preserve the .gitolite.rc file, but I'd like to know if there are any restrictions whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#variation-maintain-these-hooks-in-the-gitolite-admin-repo), you can put hooks in the repository.  The documentation doesn't make any particular warning regarding the practice, so it seems that Gitolite will happily ignore anything other than the config file and the key files.